# XMPP for multiplayer feature - design question

Tags: xmpp, multiplayer

There is a game that currently is played on standalone computers.
I want to create an add-on that allows the players to interconnect. For that I think XMPP seems to be a suitable platform.

The messages that shall be exchanged is presence/roster so users can find each other, structures messages to send items or money and generic text messages for comment and fun. In later versions I'd like to experiment with some 'business logic' to send out global changes for the world or missions and such.

My question is how users get hooked up to each other. Imagine someone creates an XMPP account. How does he start meeting the others?
Or, in general how would the users see each other if they have independent accounts? Should they all join one first multi-user-chat? Should there be one monitoring component to send invites and update rosters?

If, inside the game players can enter different areas, would it make sense to have one multi-user-chat per game area?

I know these are many questions but maybe from them you get the design problem I am facing, and I'd be happy to get some clues how this could get implemented.

Comment: There a multiple solutions to what you want to achieve. In regular XMPP user interact by exchanging their JIDs (JabberIDs) and presence subscription (to see who is online or not). If you have control over the server you can provision user user for them to ease the process. Regarding per-game chat: you can either use MUC (the first groupchat protocol) or MIX (the modern take on gropuchat based on PubSub, that tries to mitigate various shortcommings of MUC)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found the answer.

The game acts as XMPP client. It sill connect automatically to a multi-user-chat that is hardcoded in the game. With the correct parameters given, the XMPP server will create the chat room on the first user to connect. Subsequent users will simply join the same room.

This given, every user will automatically receive presence messages for all users in that room. From this the client knows the other player's addresses and can send messages to specific players. Messages addressed to the room will automatically be relayed to all other users.

So the problem I saw above is actually very easy to solve within XMPP.